# What is the format of Xlib ZPixmap format

Tags: xlib, pixmap

does anyone know what is XLib ZPixmap format for 32/24bit images/pixmaps. Is it RGB(A) or BGR(A), etc. or highly implementation dependent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pixmaps have no color, period.  They're just arrays of pixel values.  The only drawables in X that have a color interpretation are Windows (channels defined by Visuals), Pictures (channels defined by Picture Formats), and GLX drawables (channels defined by either a GLX visual or an fbconfig).  Any "color" interpretation you want to put on a pixmap is a function of where those pixels are going to end up (or, where they came from).  If you're going to put them into a Window, look at the Visual of the Window to discover what the color channel masks are.

[edit: added GLX drawable info]

Comment: This is a great answer.  I had the same question.   Would you be able to post some Xlib sample code?